# How to correctly unit test yargs in typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, yargs

There are 2 points that I need to be explained
- How to reset yargs without using deprecated .reset() method; (.global() method instead, but how ??)
- how do I pass in the command line to yargs as typed in by the user

Given the following test:

```js
import * as yargs from 'yargs';
describe.only('how to write a unit test for yargs with typescript', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    yargs.reset(); // No, but how do we get a new yargs instance?
  });
  it('yargs', () => {
    const usernameOption = {
      alias: 'username',
      describe: 'website username'
    };
    // (['login', '-u', 'jimmy']) => where does this go, without causing a build error
    // TS2349: This expression is not callable
    //
    yargs.command('login', 'login to website', (y: yargs.Argv): yargs.Argv => {
      return y.option('u', usernameOption);
    });
    console.log(`>>> ${JSON.stringify(yargs.argv)}`);

    // the above outputs:
    // >>> result: {"_":[],"$0":"/Users/Plastikfan/dev/github/js/aergia-cli-ts/node_modules/.bin/mocha"}
    //
    // how to reset yargs without using deprecated .reset() method?
    // => .global() ?
    //
  });
});
```

if I try to pass in the command line into yargs:

```
    yargs(['login', '-u', 'jimmy']).command('login', 'login to website', (y: yargs.Argv): yargs.Argv => {
      return y.option('u', usernameOption);
    });
```

I see the following error 'TS2349: This expression is not callable':

> ERROR in
>   /Users/Plastikfan/dev/github/js/aergia-cli-ts/tests/yargs/yargs-builder.impl.spec.ts
>   ./tests/yargs/yargs-builder.impl.spec.ts [tsl] ERROR in
>   /Users/Plastikfan/dev/github/js/aergia-cli-ts/tests/yargs/yargs-builder.impl.spec.ts(89,5)
>         TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type '{ default: Argv<{}>; alias(shortName: K1,
>   longName: K2 | readonly K2[]): Argv<{ [key in K2]: {}[K1]; }>;
>   alias(shortName: K2, longName: K1
>   | readonly K1[]): Argv<...>; alias(shortName: string | readonly
>   string[], longName: string | readonly st...' has no call signatures.

I've been scanning around for other yargs unit tests and I found these tests in yargs: [yargs completion tests](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/test/completion.js)

in particular:

```js
yargs(['./completion', '--get-yargs-completions', 'apple'])
```

ie yargs is invoked (), but this is where I get the error when I try it in a typescript test. Note that the example quoted is a javascript test, and it also uses the deprecated .reset() function inside beforeEach.

I originally had "esModuleInterop": true, in tsconfig, but setting this to false made no difference.